# Glyphicons is not showing in Browser using Bootstrap in html code?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, web-deployment

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Bootstrap Glyphicons</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <link href="bootstrap-4.0.0-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

    <div class="container">

        <div class="page-header">
            <h1>Bootstrap Glyphicons</h1>
            <p class="lead">Icons that are actual, real-life fonts! This means no Photoshopping required :)</p>
        </div><!-- page-header -->

        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right"></span></p>

        <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-music"></span> An icon in a header!</h3>

        <p><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> There's an icon for just about anything you can think of!</p>

        <p>You can link an icon like so: <a href="index.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span></a></p>


        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg btn-info">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> A button with an icon
        </button>

        <br><br>

        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>
            You may use icons in alert messages, too!
        </div>

        <br>

        <h4>Use icons for User Interface design</h4>

        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pause"></span></button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>


        <hr>
    </div><!-- container -->


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
   <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

hey I am trying to show icon in the browser but it is not showing in the browser while I am using proper bootstrap tags but didn't find any icon in the browser 
is it any tag error or something please help me to understand it
** is it necessary ** to use all the cdn links like jQuery javascript are use or choose manually which one is the better decision.

Comment: by the looks of it, the link to your CSS is not correct, do you get any errors in the console?

Comment: nope I change several times to finding the error but CSS directory is perfect as in my system.directory and subdirectory path have no error

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're using Bootstrap 4, and according to [its documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#components), in that version they dropped the Glyphicons icon font, that means, from v4.0, Bootstrap won't offer Glyphicon support.

If you need to use icons in Bootstrap 4, you need to search alternatives like Font Awesome and add it by yourself, or get down to [Bootstrap 3.3.7](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#glyphicons) and use it.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the glyphicons. Put this after importing bootstrap

`<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Answer (score 0):

Replacing your line

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

with

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

solved the issue for me.

You are also trying to reference a local version of the 4.0.0 css, you probably don't need that line.